# How can I write this jQuery in standard JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little jQuery function that displays a pop up window, but it's not working on a particular website I want to include it on.

```
$(".reg_faqs").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
});
```

The jQuery version I am using is 1.11.2

Is it possible to write this function in "standard" non-library JavaScript? I would like to check it's not a problem with conflicting jQuery scripts on the page, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and quite trivial. Look into `document.getElementsByClassName`, `addEventListener`, and `.href`.

Comment: whether the elements `reg_faqs` are dynamically created? you might have to look at event delegation if the elements are created dynamically

Comment: There is only one `<a class="reg_faqs" ...>` on the page, luckily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure is

```
function handle(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open(this.href, "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
}

var el = document.querySelector('.req_faqs');

el.addEventListener('click',handle);
```

Comment: I see a `$(..)` call in there ;-)

Comment: Oops. Copy & pasted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName( 'reg_faqs' ), function( elem ) {
  elem.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
     window.open(this.href, "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
     event.preventDefault();
  }, false);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to set `jQuery.noConflict()` after jquery is loaded.

> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

After this replace all of $ to jQuery.